# How to make rectangle link with exceeding div in it

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

In our website we have got this button:

[image: example]

Now we need to create link from that but without this tape on top of it.

The problem is that it also creates link in empty space (top left corner of tape).

### What we tried

Make the tape straight and rotate it with CSS. It is quite good, except the thing that it is not supported in older browsers. Also it would be better to keep that link just in that white space (container div).

### HTML

```
<div class="box-body buttons-text clearfix">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="tape"></div>
        <img src="/images/fire.png" class="left">
        <span>HOT JOB</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box-body {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.tape {
    background: url("../images/tape.png") center 0 no-repeat;
    width: 145px;
    height: 54px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 46px;
    left: 83px;
}
```

Comment: you must exclude the tape from that link element, because events are bubbling in DOM hierarchy

Comment: can't you move the `<div class="tape"></div>` from `a` tag and put it outside. and then give the `position:relative` to parent div.

Comment: I would try removing the div and using an anchor which is displayed as block instead, and assigning to it the picture as background and the text as the anchor title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that it also creates link in empty space (top left corner of tape).

For modern browsers, you could use [`pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events):

```
.tape {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Really thank you, we will use your solution. And old browsers. Well... I don't want to be vulgar :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).

1. Use the button as an image.
2. Then use a correct image-map to define clickable area of the image.

Comment: Thanks. We were also thinking about this, but we really dont't want to have this button as an image. Mainly because there will be prabably more buttons on our website with different sizes.